# How could I get to Trinidad & Tobago without going through US from Kenya?

Tags: tickets

How could I get to Jamaica without going through US from Kenya?

Comment: Please state your exact constraints? What rough date , what is your nationality, what visa, do or do you not have? Can you get a Schengen Visa?

Comment: Do you want to go to Jamaica or Trinidad & Tobago?

Comment: Via Cuba might be another possibility, with flights from some African airports, but I'm not sure exactly where in the Caribbean you want to be.

Comment: We really can’t properly answer this without at least knowing your citizenship. A travel agent should be able to help. You could also try inputting your details and feasible transit point(s) into Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

Comment: Trinidad is not in Jamaica.

Comment: @RobertColumbia similarly, Jamaica is not in Trinidad.

Comment: Trinidad and Tobago are separate islands and each has an international airport. You can get between the two by sea or air. Tobago is more popular as a tourist destination.

Answer (score 2):

A few options

1. Eurowings is flying non-stop Frankfurt to Kingston a few times a week starting in November 3
2. Edelweiss Air flies non-stop Zurich to Kingston once a week starting Nov 1
3. Virgin Atlantic flies non-stop from London Heathrow
4. I think British Airways flies a few times a week from Gatwick
5. If none of those play out, you can also try to route through a different Caribbean island from Europe.

Almost all of these will require separate tickets, so you will need to be able to enter or at least do a non-airside transfer in the transit country.